# Possible "Snippet VM"?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I just recently got [a post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/171391/9357) reopened. I tried out the snippet on there and Chrome said:

> this site is trying to load unsafe scripts
>   (load unsafe scripts)

When I did, it automatically set Code Review as <strike>https://</strike>codereview.stackexchange.com.

Is it possible to have a "VM" as in an `iframe` with some fancy JavaScript that makes it act like an **actual** web browser and doesn't mark the site as **unsafe**?

Comment: No repro on Chrome 61.0.3163.91 (latest version).  Check to make sure you have the latest version and that it's not some kind of hiccup.

Comment: im in the latest version and its permanantly stuck on "not secure"

Comment: In that case, you can add the [tag:bug] tag as it may stand out more to the devs who may have an answer (they would be the only ones to review this feature request anyway).

Comment: I get an XSS insecure message, because No Script prevents that (Firefox latest). However, in vanilla Chrome (latest), it works fine.